# Prevent from submitting on false return Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, onsubmit

It seems I'm having issues understanding exactly how form submission works...

Here is my event listener for submitting the from:

```
    function createEventListeners() {
    var orderForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    if (orderForm.addEventListener) {
        orderForm.addEventListener("submit", validateForm, false);
    }//end if
        else if (orderForm.attachEvent) {
            orderForm.attachEvent("onsubmit", validateForm);
    }//end else
}//end function createEventListeners()
```

Here is the code for validating the form:

```
    function validateForm(evt){
    var valid = true;

    if (testLength(document.expReport.lname) == false){
        valid = false;
    }
    if (testLength(document.expReport.fname) == false){
        valid = false;
    }
    if (testLength(document.expReport.summary) == false){
        valid = false;
    }
    if (testLength(document.expReport.init) == false){
        valid = false;
    }

    //Call the testPattern() function with the department field for the field parameter.
    if (testPattern(document.expReport.deptID, /DEPT\d\d\d\d\d/) == false){
        valid = false;
    }

    //Call the testPattern() function with the account field object for the field parameter.
    if (testPattern(document.expReport.accID, /ACT\d\d\d\d\d\d/) == false){
        valid = false;
    }

    //Call the testPattern() function with the project field for the field parameter.
    if (testPattern(document.expReport.projID, /PROJ-..-\d\d\d\d/) == false){
        valid = false;
    }

    //Call the testPattern() function for the ssn field
    if ((testPattern(document.expReport.ssn, /\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d/) || testPattern(document.expReport.ssn, /\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d/)) == false){
        valid = false
    }

    if (testDates() == false){
        valid = false;
    }

    if (valid == false){
        window.alert("Please fill out all required fields in the proper format.")
    }

    return valid;
}//end function validateForm(evt)
```

My issues is that even though the validate function is returning a false value the form submission still takes place.

I've done research on how to prevent this from being the case but it seems that most people just use the .preventDefaults() method to get around this. My issue is that the form that I'm working with contains text fields that are optional, thus if the user chooses to not fill them out, he will still be presented with a false return.

Is there an issue with how I'm setting up the listener for submission?
I've also tried to look up what can be done with the evt parameter but there is nothing there that is explaining why it refuses to function as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're ultimately not doing anything with the validation result.

Your function `validateForm` will be getting invoked when the event fires, and it's probably working fine, but its return value goes nowhere.

Without seeing the whole page it's not possible to say what change you should make, but hopefully this is enough to shed light on what's needed so you can fix it.

Comment: Yes i recognize that this is the root of my problem, but how do i use the evt to return a false value when one of those expressions is false?

Comment: @Figgueh as I say, you haven't included enough of the page to be sure of the detailed answer. As a guess, I suggest scrapping the script that adds the eventhandler, and instead just use the form attribute, something like: `<form name="ff1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">`. If still stuck please edit your question to include the missing parts of the page.